# getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when running a jar file made using matlab

Tags: java, matlab, jar, noclassdeffounderror, matlab-deployment

I am having trouble running a java package I made by deploying my function in matlab. This is what I have tried and these are my errors.

I deployed a jar file of my function from matlab. I tried to run it with the following steps:
1. change the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/runtime/glnxa64/:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/:opencv`

1. in the deployed project, my classes are in a folder called `javafiles` so I run it as:

`java -cp ../javafiles.jar:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/toolbox/javabuilder/jar/javabuilder.jar:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64/libmwMATLAB_imagesci_res.so:mex:opencv/. -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/runtime/glnxa64/ javafiles.Class1`

Here `opencv` and `mex` are folders in the current directory which contain some shared libraries and mex files required to run my project. Upon doing this I get the error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mathworks/toolbox/javabuilder/internal/MWComponentInstance
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWComponentInstance
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 13 more`

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: 1) did you first try compiling it using `javac`? If so, post the full command that you used.  2) ur `so` file should be there in `java.library.path`, not in `classpath`  3) ur `java` command above seems incomplete. Which is the main class are you running here?

Comment: I am trying to run `javafiles.Class1` its a bit confusing in the formatting, there is a space between `Djava.library.path=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/runtime/glnxa64/` and `javafiles.Class1`